# phpass hash similar functionality in swift

Tags: ios, swift, hash, phpass

My wordpress backend is using phpass hash algorithm and giving me phpass using web service. In ios end in swift I am trying to generate same phpass hash in swift. Below are codes in swift and php. Both have same input but output is different. So question is that how can i get same output. Am I missing anything?

Php code :

```
<?php
function phpassHash($password, $salt,$iterations){
    $hash = hash('md5', $salt.$password, TRUE);
    for($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++){
        $hash = hash('md5', $hash.$password, TRUE);
    }
    return $hash;
}
$result = phpassHash("a_test_password","MsdvACyA", 8192);
echo bin2hex($result); 
?>
```

Swift code :

```
func md5(string: String) -> String {
        var digest = [UInt8](count: Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)
        if let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            CC_MD5(data.bytes, CC_LONG(data.length), &digest)
        }
        var digestHex = ""
        for index in 0..<Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH) {
            digestHex += String(format: "%02x", digest[index])
        }

        return digestHex
    }



func phpassHash(password: String, salt: String, iterations: Int) -> String {
        var hash = md5(salt+password)
        for _ in 0..<iterations {
            hash = md5(hash+password)
        }
        return hash;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were too eager to convert the bytes array into `String` in your `md5` function. As an example, this changes the meaning of the integer `0x47` to the string `47`. Your first call to `md5()` returns the correct hash, but if you `md5()` that again, it will go wrong since it's a string now instead of an array of bytes as in PHP. Notice that in PHP, you call `bin2hex` at the very last step.

Since the `CC_MD5` function in CommonCrypt like to deal with array of bytes, keep everything as bytes and writer wrapper if necessary.

First, let's define some helper functions:

```
extension String {
    // Return the bytes that make up the string according to UTF-8 encoding
    var bytes: [UInt8] {
        get {
            return self.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
                .dropLast() // C strings are null-terminated so we need to drop the last byte
                .map { UInt8(bitPattern: $0) }
        }
    }
}

// Convert an array of bytes to a hex string
func toHexString(bytes: [UInt8]) -> String {
    return bytes.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joinWithSeparator("")
}
```

Now you can write your hash fucntions:

```
// Allow you to quickly hash a string. We don't really use it here
func md5(string: String) -> [UInt8] {
    return md5(string.bytes)
}

func md5(bytes: [UInt8]) -> [UInt8] {
    var digest = [UInt8](count: Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)

    CC_MD5(bytes, CC_LONG(bytes.count), &digest)
    return digest
}

func phpassHash(password: String, salt: String, iterations: Int) -> [UInt8] {
    let passwordBytes = password.bytes
    let saltBytes     = salt.bytes

    var hash = md5(saltBytes + passwordBytes)
    for _ in 0..<iterations {
        hash = md5(hash + passwordBytes)
    }

    return hash
}

let password   = "a_test_password"
let salt       = "MsdvACyA"
let iterations = 8192
let assHash    = phpassHash(password, salt: salt, iterations: iterations)

print(toHexString(assHash)) // 42a89278a28860f223a10fdb43b5d4b2
```

Comment: @SusimSamanta can you please post a function to Encrypt string using PHpass in iOS?

Comment: @Vishal_iOS_Developer above function should work well.